# How to disable a button until fields are filled with entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working with a team who uses Wix to build their website. I am new to Wix, a new form was created and i want to disable the "Register" button until all text input fields are filled with entries and the checkbox is checked. I wrote some codes as i was studying Wix kind of Javascript but it is not working for me.

```
let validationMessage = '';
//$w('#button8').disable();

let schName = $w('#schoolName').value;
let schAddress = $w('#schoolAddress').value;
let schCity = $w('#schoolCity').value;
let schState = $w('#schoolState').value;
let schEmail = $w('#schoolEmail').value;
let schRegNo = $w('#schoolRegNumber').value;
let schPhoneNo = $w('#schoolPhoneNumber').value;
let schWebsite = $w('#schoolWebsite').value;
let isCheckedBox = $w('#tNa').checked;
let regButton = $w('#button8');

$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...

    // Checking to see if all fields have values. If not disable button until it does.
    if ((schName.length && schAddress.length && schCity.length &&
        schState.length && schEmail.length && schRegNo.length && schPhoneNo.length && schWebsite.length === 0) && !isCheckedBox) {

        regButton.disable();
        validationMessage += 'All fields must be filled!\n';
    } else {

    regButtion.enbaled;
    regButton.onClick((event) => {
        formSubmission(event);

    });
   }
});
```

Is there something i am doing wrong? i have used both && and & for the if statement but it is not working.

Comment: so what is the currently beahvior and how it differ from your requirement?

Comment: When i preview within Wix to test before i publish, the button is still enabled even as the text input fields are all empty with zero values. My intention is to have it disabled until the person to fill the forms starts filling all inputs with values and checks the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $w.onReady(function () {
        //TODO: write your page related code here...
        regButton.onClick((event) => {
        // Checking to see if all fields have values. If not disable button until it does.
          if ((schName.length ===0 || schAddress.length ===0 || schCity.length ===0 ||
            schState.length ===0 || schEmail.length ===0 || schRegNo.length ===0 || schPhoneNo.length ===0 || schWebsite.length === 0) || !isCheckedBox) {

            validationMessage += 'All fields must be filled!\n';
          } else {

            formSubmission(event);
          }
        });

    });
```

Comment: According to your code, it is when the button is clicked before it checks for inputs. What i want is for the button to be disabled and only to be enabled when the form is filled. The formsubmission(event) function handles for validity of every input into the fields.

Comment: i applied some sections of your code to mine i.e i changed the xx.length to xx.length ===0 and also changed the && to ||. It was able to disable the button but after i inputed values into the form, the button still remained disabled while it should be enabled acording to the latter section of my code.